# Discordjs could not catch a DiscordAPIError

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically the problem is that even if I wrap the code that causes the error in try catch, the error still stops the code, here's my code.

```js
// snip
try{
    // get user using id "does-not-exist", which does not exist
    // code stops when fetching user
    client.users.fetch('does-not-exist').then(function (user) {
        user.send('hello');
    });
}catch(err){
    console.error('message could not be sent');
}
```

Why does my code stops even if I wrap it with try catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) should be used in combination with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await). If you want to use synchronous then/catch, use the respective `.catch()` callback.

```js
client.users.fetch('does-not-exist')
   .then(function (user) {
        user.send('hello');
   })
   .catch(err => /* error handle */);
```

If you want to ignore the error void it

```js
.catch(_ => null);
```

How it would look with async await

```js
try {
   const user = await client.users.fetch('does-not-exist')
} catch (err) {
   /* Handle Error */
}
```

Comment: They are asking why the code stops even though it's in a `try/catch`. The reason is because the catch block has a `console.error` call which throws the error that was just caught

Comment: Judging by the title "Discordjs could not catch a DiscordAPIError" they are aiming to handle the API error that is emitted by `UserManager#fetch()` also, [console.error()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error) *does not stop error execution* and only "outputs an error message to the Web console."